# How do you say "Without Toothbrush" in French? or "Without Bike"? help me pls!

Tags: grammaire

How do you say "Without Toothbrush" in French? or "Without Bike"? help me pls!

Comment: I suggest you give a bit more background: in which context ?

Comment: allez, without=sans : sans brosse à dents, sans vélo.